# Recurring Action template error ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep on having this error

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Here's my show.html.erb

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <% if booking.checkin_on > Date.today %>
  <% if booking.status == "Confirmed" %>
  <li class="dashboard">
  <%= cl_image_tag(booking.bed.photo.path, width: 400, height: 300, crop: :fill, class: "pdt-image hidden-xs" ) %>
  <div class='product-body'>
    <h2><%= booking.bed.title %></h2>
    <p>City: <strong><%= booking.bed.city %></strong></p>
    <p>Address: <strong><%= booking.bed.address %></strong></p>
    <p>Total price: <strong><%= booking.value %> €</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled hidden-sm hidden-xs padded">
      <li><strong>Your booking is confirmed !</strong></li>
      <li class="text-right"><%= link_to "Delete this booking", booking_path(booking), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-default", data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} %> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>

  <% if booking.status == "Canceled" %>
  <li class="dashboard">
  <%= cl_image_tag(booking.bed.photo.path, width: 400, height: 300, crop: :fill, class: "pdt-image hidden-xs" ) %>
  <div class='product-body'>
    <h2><%= booking.bed.title %></h2>
    <p>City: <strong><%= booking.bed.city %></strong></p>
    <p>Address: <strong><%= booking.bed.address %></strong></p>
    <p>Total price: <strong><%= booking.value %> €</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled hidden-sm hidden-xs padded">
      <li><p><%= booking.bed.user.first_name%> canceled your booking </p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

And here's my my_bookings controller

```
class My::BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @bookings = Booking.where(user_id: current_user.id)
   @bookings = Booking.all
   @beds = Bed.all
  end

  def show
   set_booking
   @bed = @booking.bed
  end

private
 def set_booking
  @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

Any suggestions? Or anything I can't see? I have tried almost everything I can think of at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: why are you assigning `@bookings` 2x? The 2nd one will overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declairing the @bookings variable on your `show` method, which explains the crash. It appears you are declaring it as you wanted it on the first line of your `index` method. Just change where you declare it, and it shall be alright.

Also, to avoid further headaches, you should refactor the `set_booking` method to:

```
def set_booking
 @booking = Booking.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

by deafult `.find()` will crash your view if it doesn't find anything

`.find_by`, on the other hand, will return an empty answer, so it won't crash. Also, it's more versatile, since this way you can search from innumerous other variables set in your model, i.e. `name`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  This is a good suggestion, however it doesn’t answer the specific question at hand which is probably why someone left that downvote. Consider adding it as a comment, or editing your current answer to address the specific problem the OP asked about. Happy hacking.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I mischecked the variable being iterated on the `html`. Fixed the answer for a proper one, and added my previous answer as a suggestion to avoid future complications. Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that! I just now have to figure out how to get the info printed out on my html file. It's totally not reading anything!

Comment: Let me see if I can help you with that. I don't know exactly how you declared your `@bookings` variable, but suposing you used the same method as the first time you declared it on the presented `def index`, using the `user_id`. Are you sure this User actually has Bookings? Or, I suppose you are using `gem 'enumerize'` for the booking status. In your enumerize declaration, did you set the values as symbles? If so, when checking for the booking.status, compare it to a lowercase value. If you could update the files above, I may be able to help you more. Sorry for long reply lol.

Answer (score 0):

By convention in Rails controller actions (`index` and `show` in your case) render views with same names, in your case those might be `intex.html.erb` and `show.html.erb`. In your show method you define two variables: `@bed` and `@booking` and in your view (`show.html.erb`) you try to loop variable `@bookings` which you have not defined in your controller action. Thus, you are getting this error.

Looks like you need to rename `show.html.erb` to `index.html.erb` as you are listing bookings and their information in it.